# How to read a text file and insert the data into next line on getting \n character

Tags: python-3.x, linux, text

I have a text file where data is comma delimited with a litral `\n` character in between, i would like to insert the data into newline just after getting the `\n` character.

### text file sample:

```
'what,is,your,name\n','my,name,is,david.hough\n','i,am,a,software,prof\n','what,is,your,name\n','my,name,is,eric.knot\n','i,am,a,software,prof\n','what,is,your,name\n','my,name,is,fisher.cold\n','i,am,a,software,prof\n',..
```

### expected:

I need the output in the below form.

```
'what,is,your,name',
'my,name,is,david.hough',
'i,am,a,software,prof',
```

**Tried:**

```
file1 = open("test.text", "r")
Lines = file1.readlines()
for line in Lines:
  print(line)
```

**result:**

```
'what,is,your,name\n','my,name,is,david.hough\n','i,am,a,software,prof\n','what,is,your,name\n','my,name,is,eric.knot\n','i,am,a,software,prof\n','what,is,your,name\n','my,name,is,fisher.cold\n','i,am,a,software,prof\n',..
```

Comment: as \n is in quotes it will become \\n, you can use Lines = file1.read().split("\\n")

Comment: that did not helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well my comment does exactly what you asked, break lines at \n. your data is structured quite weirdly, but if you want the expected result that badly you can use regex

```
import re

file1 = open("test.text","r")
Lines = re.findall(r'\'.*?\',',file1.read().replace("\\n",""))
for line in Lines:
  print(line)
```

Answer (score -1):

Well you don't need push data to the other line manually. The `\n` does that work when you run the code.

I guess the problem is that you used quotes very frequently, try using a single pair of quotes and use \n after the first sentence and yeah without white space

```
'what,is,your,name\nmy,name,is,david.hough\ni,am,a,software,prof'
```

Comment: simran,  please read the post again, i have the data in text file with `\n` character which i need in the expected form, what is your answer here? that is question i have data in the form as i have in post.

Comment: I have edited my post anyways try to replace it once:)

Comment: How i can get expected data?